# What is recommended to use pydbus or dbus-python and what are the differences?

Tags: python-3.x, gtk, dbus, dbus-python

I'm trying to implement a dbus service that will be then used in a Gtk-application.

There are two python modules (pydbus vs. dbus-python) claiming to do just that. I've been unable to find any pro and contra list of both implementations.

My short question is:

#### What is the recommended way to implement a dbusservice in Python3?

Comment: Your question is opinion-based which makes it a non stackoverflow question.

Comment: It might be yes, but it has a lot of views so is probably interesting to others and as far as I know there are most/all possible solutions in the answers and the answers helped me a lot in my decision-making.

Answer (score 2):

pydbus is better because dbus-python was deprecated.

You can read more here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/DbusExamples

To be honest it seems that pydbus is not actively maintained today, the last release is from 2016. There is a third way which is to use GDBus from GLib using PyGObject.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... GDBus from Glib - are there any samples howtos? I usually find it very hard to translate the C-api to the python one. As you said pydbus is not really maintained however dbus-python gets monthly commits in its repos so maybe not deprecated? As said I'm confused.

Comment: Hmm I could not find an example in Python for a server from a rapid search. Here is a nice example for a client: https://aleksander.es/data/GNOMEASIA2014%20-%20Introduction%20to%20DBus.pdf

Comment: And here is an answer with some good advice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54113389/migration-from-dbus-to-gdbus-in-python-3

Comment: So... in summary so far - there are two pythonic options both with uncertain future and one stable api that is rather hard to use. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: `pydbus` does not support async calls, even though a PR adding them has submitted for a long time, but it has not been merged yet and I don't see signs of that happening soon or ever.

Answer (score 2):

Since pydbus development is practically dead since 2018 the best choice for a pythonic implementation is probably [dasbus](https://github.com/rhinstaller/dasbus). Dasbus is directly inspired by pydbus, intended to replace it and is in active development.