# Python D-Bus: Subscribe to signal and read property with dasbus

Tags: python, linux, dbus

How to monitor and read Ubuntu's "Night Light" status via D-Bus using Python with [dasbus](https://dasbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)? I can't figure out the API docs on how to read a property or subscribe to a signal.
Likely candidates:

- [`dasbus.client.property.get()`](https://dasbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dasbus.client.property.html#dasbus.client.property.PropertyProxy.get)
- [`GLibClient.subscribe()`](https://dasbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dasbus.client.handler.html?highlight=subscribe#dasbus.client.handler.GLibClient.subscribe_signal)

The following is adapted from the basic examples and prints the interfaces and properties/signals of the object:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from dasbus.connection import SessionMessageBus
bus = SessionMessageBus()

# dasbus.client.proxy.ObjectProxy
proxy = bus.get_proxy(
    "org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color",  # bus name
    "/org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Color",  # object path
)

print(proxy.Introspect())

# read and print properties "NightLightActive" and "Temperature" from interface "org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color" in (callback) function

# subscribe to signal "PropertiesChanged" in interface "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" / register callback function
```

---

Resources

- https://pypi.org/project/dbus-python/
- [What is recommended to use pydbus or dbus-python and what are the differences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58639602/what-is-recommended-to-use-pydbus-or-dbus-python-and-what-are-the-differences)
- https://wiki.python.org/moin/DbusExamples
- [Migration from dbus to GDbus in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54113389/migration-from-dbus-to-gdbus-in-python-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [dasbus examples](https://dasbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html) and the Introspection data it looks like to get the property the dasbus is pythonic so `proxy.<property name>` works. For your example of `NightLightActive` it would be:

```py
print("Night light active?", proxy.NightLightActive)
```

For the signal you need to connect to the signal on the proxy so that seems to take the form of `proxy.<signal name>.connect` so for example:

```py
proxy.PropertiesChanged.connect(callback)
```

And this will need to have an `EventLoop` running.

My entire test was:

```py
from dasbus.connection import SessionMessageBus
from dasbus.loop import EventLoop

bus = SessionMessageBus()
loop = EventLoop()

# dasbus.client.proxy.ObjectProxy
proxy = bus.get_proxy(
    "org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color",  # bus name
    "/org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Color",  # object path
)

print("Night light active?", proxy.NightLightActive)
print("Temperature is set to:", proxy.Temperature)


def callback(iface, prop_changed, prop_invalidated):
    print("The notification:",
          iface, prop_changed, prop_invalidated)


proxy.PropertiesChanged.connect(callback)

loop.run()
```

Comment: The fade to a different Color Temperature emits many signals with `prop_changed`  = `{'Temperature': GLib.Variant('u', 6472)}` for individual steps.

Comment: Get the value with `prop_changed['Temperature'].get_uint32()`

Comment: Better use [`unpack()`](https://github.com/GNOME/pygobject/blob/master/gi/overrides/GLib.py#L237), it returns native Python type.